# Unhandled exception in script python exe

Tags: python, json, tkinter, exe

Estuve viendo un video para poder tratar al proyecto como ejecutable. Modo `py` en visual funciona, y no marca error, al poner:

```
python -m PyInstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./umaru.ico main.py
```

Me sale:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 7, in
>
> File "claseInterfaz.py", line 69, in init
>
> File "tkinter__init.py", line 2136, in wm_iconbitmap
> _tkinter.TclError: bitmap "Imagenes/Logo.ico" not defined

Pero `C:\Users\victo\Downloads\IntegradorDefinitivo` dentro tiene carpeta `imágenes` y los **archivos de clase** y el `main`

Y Para que justamente no me de problemas yo hago:
import os
Establecer el icono de la ventana
carpetaDeTodosLosArchivos = os.path.dirname(file__)
self.carpetaImagenes = os.path.join(carpetaDeTodosLosArchivos, "Imagenes")
iconoLogo = os.path.join(self.carpetaImagenes, "Logo.ico")

[image: Pero sale error... Alguien sabe que puedo hacer?]

[image: El error]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar la flag --onefile por --onedir ya que lo que quieres compilar es un directorio. También podrías probar a usar auto-py-to-exe (que por debajo usa pyinstaller) que tiene una interfaz gráfica más fácil de usar.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).